# CSS not applied to PHP generated options list in html select

Tags: php, html, css, google-chrome, opera

**Updated:**
The problem is not with dynamic generation, but with the number of items.

See demo: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w7MThv1tTy4INKHRQ4SS?p=preview)

---

I am having to select boxes on my site, both styled the same as dark background with white text:

```
select {
    border: 1px solid #505050;
    background: #151515;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

The CSS is applied correctly to statically created select box:

```
<select name="foo">
  <option value="bar">bar</option>
  <option value="...">...</option>
</select>
```

However I also have PHP function to build the options dynamically:

```
function generateOptions() {
    $string = "";
    $res    = $database->connection->query("SELECT name FROM something");

    while ($row = $res->fetch()) {
        $option = '<option value="' . $row['name'] . '">' . $row['name'] . '</option>';
        $string = $string . $option;
    }

    return $string;
}
```

When I try to insert these options into `select` the CSS is not applied (the options color is black (default browser color)), and I have no idea why. Do you have any suggestions?

```
<?php $list = generateOptions(); ?>

<form action="#" method="POST">
    <select name="foo">
        <?php echo $list; ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

---

Edit: This happens in Google Chrome and Opera.

Comment: try this in CSS..`option{ color:#fff;}`.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't help. Btw. I edited the question - the problem occurs in Google Chrome and Opera. Firefox is working correctly.

Comment: Can you create a demo of the code?

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem in demo code (basic html with production css).  I copied production html div sructure and the problem arisen, so I am going to dig deeper into it... Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is with chrome limiting the number of options styled for performance reasons https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=513339